# type 'File/*1*/' can't be assigned to the type 'File/*2* - 'File/*1*/' is from 'dart:io'.- 'File/*2*/' is from 'package:universal_io/src/io/file.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, supabase

I want to upload image to my supabase storage using this function, and I am using `riverpod_flutter` for state management, here is my code:

```
class ServicesRepository{
 Future<String> uploadServicesImageApi(String path, File image) async {
    final response = await Supabase.instance.client.storage
        .from('services')
        .upload(path, image);

    return response;
  }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: The argument type 'File/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File/*2*/'. lib/…/repository/services_repository.dart:38  - 'File/*1*/' is from 'dart:io'. - 'File/*2*/' is from 'package:universal_io/src/io/file.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/universal_io-2.0.4/
```

I changed my import from `import 'dart:io'` to `import 'dart:io' as i` and my code to this:

```
Future<String> uploadServicesImageApi(String path, i.File image) async {
    final response = await Supabase.instance.client.storage
        .from('services')
        .upload(path, image as i.File);

    return response;
}
```

but I'm still getting the same error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't use `dart:io` on the web as it's a native-only library provided by the Dart VM, so this will cause issues for you if you're not already testing against a web target.

Second, the error you're seeing states that you're trying to use `File` from `dart:io` where `File` from `package:universal_io` is expected. To fix this, you need to either:

- Drop your `dart:io` import (which you'll need to do anyway to target web)
- Place your `dart:io` behind a library prefix like you have in your second example, but replacing `i.File` with `File`
- Hide `File` from your `dart:io` import by doing: `import dart:io hide File;`

Comment: Can you give me a full code, please?

Comment: I will appreciate a lot.